# Wordpress custom post type modify data in rows

Tags: wordpress

Check the image below

[image: View more explaination]

I have already modify the link for Edit link using "post_row_actions" filter.. But i need the help with this..

Comment: You want to change the URL of the above link? Why? It's the default one created by wordpress when you create CPT.

Comment: Yes i do want to change the link of title.. I have moved that default link to Edit settings in post row actions..

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want to remove the link from your title altogether? To have just a regular title that is not linking to anywhere?

Comment: I want to change the link for title.. Do we have any filter or actions available for this??? I do not want to alter any default pages of core wordpress

Comment: Change to what? You can't change links in the backend (the part `/edit.php?post_type={cpt_name}`).

Comment: DId you see that image ?? , I pointed arrow .. "ecadmin65" , I want to change the link for that title..

Comment: And your question is still not clear. Change to what?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107305/discussion-between-hasmukh-mistry-and-dingo-d).

Comment: your question is ambiguous. kindly can your elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change links for the backend. If you want to change link of your post use Settings -> Permalinks. You can change the links of posts, pages, etc.